# Reading a .dat image file

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image stored in .dat format an I want to read and then show the image. imshow and imread functions don't work.what are the other functions that I can use?
Note that I'm using Matlab R2010a

Comment: You need to know more about the image format. .dat can include many different things.

Comment: 'DAT' is not a file format. It is an unhelpful extension that lets you know that the file contains DATa. If the file contains text, you'll need to figure out how to parse it, which might be possible by looking at it. If it's just binary data, you'll need to figure out who gave you this file and throttle them until they give you the specification for it.

Comment: try to change extension to .jpg, .png, .bmp etc and pray that any of them works...

Comment: You have to tell us the source of those DAT files. I used to deal with dat-files that contained an image and it was some proprietary format. I either had to use manifacturer's SDK or parse them by myself (the format was known).

Answer (score 0):

The load function should work

load("filename.dat")

Comment: It does not work and I get the error  ??? Error using ==> load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file D:\RS\911130 TM bands\b2.dat
"+*+-".